# Is extern needed for function defined in another file?

Tags: c

Say I have the following header and .c file declared within my project. Imagine Type is a data type that I declared.

```
//header1.h
typedef struct Typing {
   int size;
} Type;
Type foo(int);
int randomNum;
```

And here is the .c file

```
//header1.c
#include "header1.h"
Type foo(int size) {
   Type type;
   type.size = 100;
   return type;
}
```

Let's say there is some other file called example.h that needed to call this function foo from header. Does it matter if I add the work extern for the function or variable? From what I hear, it is needed for variables.

```
//example.h
#include "header1.h"
extern int randomNum;
extern Type foo(int);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extern` is needed on `extern int randomNum;` to keep the declaration from being a definition.  If you have a definition of a variable in your header file, you will get multiple definition errors at link time.

Functions are `extern` by default, so you don't need it there.

Comment: @Moderators: You should not have removed the lengthy discussion that was here.